# The method triangleLengths is undefined for type Triangles

Tags: java, eclipse, object, methods, types

I am a newbie to java and have been tasked with making a program that takes 3 inputs and then evaluates them as sides of a triangle to decide what type of triangle it is, however I am getting the error in the title.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Triangles {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> triangleLengths = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {

        System.out.print("Triangle length #" + i + ": ");
        triangleLengths.add(i,user_input.next());   
    }

    if (triangleLengths(0) == triangleLengths(1) == triangleLengths(2)) {

        System.out.println("This triangle is an equilateral triangle");

    }
```

etc

The problem I'm having is on the line with the "if" statement where I get the error in the title. Help would be greatly appreciated.

---

---

---

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the line `if (triangleLengths(0) == triangleLengths(1) == triangleLengths(2)) {`

to

```
if (triangleLengths.get(0) == triangleLengths.get(1) == triangleLengths.get(2)) {
```

**Note** there is another issue in your if condition. Remember that `If` accepts a boolean
so modify it to

```
 if (triangleLengths.get(0) == triangleLengths.get(1) && triangleLengths.get(1) == triangleLengths.get(2)) {
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Got it working now, I appreciate your help :)

Comment: @JakeB Accepting answer is the stackoverflow way of saying thank you